# Trying to use config values inside test function Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to test a middleware that uses the some `config()` values but it doesn't work. I'm getting

> `Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [config] does not exist.`

This is not a new issue in the framework (https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9733) but I just can't get it to work and it was closed in an unsatisfactory manner.

I've tried :

- Not using the config helper and instead using the Facade, but the facade root is not set in a testing environment.
- Using a new instance of the config repository itself but well... it's empty.

Any ideas?

#### My middleware's handle function:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $result = $this->apiCall()
    if($result->fails) { // Evaluates to true
        throw new \Exception('message with config value'.config('option')); // throws error
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

#### Test function

```
public function testMiddleware()
{
    $request = Request::create('/login', 'POST');
    $middleware = new MyMiddleware;

    $this->expectException(\Exception::class);
    $response = $middleware->handle($request, function() {});
}
```

Comment: Are you using [Orchestra testbench](https://github.com/orchestral/testbench)? If not, this package will load all required classes for you. ;)

Comment: No, I'm not since this is not a package for Laravel. Also, this test should be simple enough not to require any additional dev dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this test wasn't working was very dumb. I created the test with the command

```
php artisan make:test MyTestCase --unit
```

Since I passed the `--unit` flag, it was extending PHPUnit's TestCase class instead of Laravel's own.